# How high can Minecraft spiders jump?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How high can spiders jump, and can they leap up on to a wall and climb from there? For instance, can a spider jump up to the lip in any of these (O is ground, X is wall):

```
              X
        X     XX
  X     XX     X
  XX     X     X
   X     X     X
OOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO
```

Everyone says you need to put a lip on your wall to keep spiders out, but nobody says if there is a minimum height before it is effective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always put my lip just high enough so that I don't bump my head on it (that is, with 2 blocks of air between the ground and the lip). I have watched it stop spiders and have never encountered a spider above the lip. [James' answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/23366) is correct about the spider AI.

Answer (score 5):

While they can jump, I am not sure of the height to try and give you a value (The wiki is empty)

What I can speak to is that the spider AI will generally walk forward and then jump up when it needs to, resulting in them being Under the lip and hitting their heads on it. While they can jump up to the lower ones, it would be a timing issue whether or not they made it.

Answer (score 0):

I am making a fighting arena round a spawner and I have made the iron bars 4 high and the spiders can't jump that

Comment: But can they climb it?

Comment: yes lol but only one could

Answer (score -1):

The minimum height a spider can jump is about 15 blocks high. It doesn't matter about the lip, it does not even work.( or at least when I tried it) so, you should build your building pretty high, if you do not want spiders invading your building.

Comment: That's just plain wrong. Spiders can maybe *climb* 15 blocks but never jump that high. Lips on walls are a solid strategy starting at the third block-level of the wall.